# How to stop Hibernate from eagerly fetching a relationship when it is mapped using a column (referencedColumnName) different than the primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm mapping a relationship that does not use the entity's primary key. Using "referencedColumnName" with a column different than the primary key causes hibernate to eagerly fetch the association, by issuing an extra select, even when it's tagged with FetchType.LAZY.

My goal is to make it behave like a regular mapping, meaning it wouldn't issue an extra query every time I need to query the main entity.

I have already tried using @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY), which sorts out the problem, but it does not operate well with Jackson's (JSON parsing library) module "jackson-datatype-hibernate5", which skips hibernate lazy proxies when serializing the results.

Here is a scenario almost like the one I have that causes the problem:
Entities:

```java
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book
    implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

@Entity(name = "Publication")
@Table(name = "publication")
public class Publication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String publisher;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "isbn",
        referencedColumnName = "isbn"
    )
    private Book book;

    @Column(
        name = "price_in_cents",
        nullable = false
    )
    private Integer priceCents;

    private String currency;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Repository (Spring-Data, but you could try directly with the EntityManager):

```java
@Repository
public interface PublicationRepository extends JpaReadRepository <Publication, Long>
{
    @Query ("SELECT d FROM Publication d WHERE d.publisher = ?1 ")
    Optional <Publication> findByPublisher (String isbn);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve what you are looking for is by moving the annotatation  @Id to the isbn property.

You can leave the @GeneratedValue on the autoincrement property.

Notes:

1 - Make sure that your equals/hc are following the OID(Object ID) on your domain case the "NaturalId" ISBN.

2 - It will be good to ensure if possible on DB level that your natural ID has unique contraint on it.